# How to get whitelisted in microsoft's email network?

Tags: email, spam, microsoft, hotmail

I have been trying for the last couple of weeks to get whitelisted in the Microsoft's email network.

I can send emails from my site to gmail and yahoo with no problem. They are delivered to the right folder. However, I have not been able to do the same with hotmail, outlook, and live.

At first, I was only able to deliver to gmail, but yahoo was being filtered and delivered to the spam folder. I fixed this by setting up SPF records and DKIM key of 1024 bits. I also using an SMTP SSL configuration and have a SPAM ASSASSINS score of under 1.

I have read that I need somehow contact Microsoft directly in order for them to whitelist my email ip. There is even a form that would allow me to do so; however, I have not been able to access this from which is supposed to accessed from this url: https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts&scrx=1

My ip is not blacklisted so I am ok there, but it is being delivered to the spam folder of this network.

So, how can I contact Microsoft to help me solve this situation?

Comment: As mentioned by others, signing up for JMRP is a good idea. Like you, I didn't start receiving reports even after completing the contract. Ultimately, I emailed `msn-snds@microsoft.com` asking for help with JMRP. After telling the rep my IP address, I started receiving spam reports within a few hours.

Answer (score 8):

We did two things:

1. Sign up with JMRP via https://postmaster.live.com/snds/JMRP.aspx
2. Sign up with SNDS via http://postmaster.live.com/snds

The JMRP application will go through a form and a document you need to sign. In our case it took about two days to get approved.

Make sure that your SPF/DKIM/DMARC is setup correctly - we are using Port25 and their tooling is quite good - cant post this link, just Google "Port25 DKIM"

Comment: Thanks Magic, I did already signed up to their two programs and signed the document; however, I never got a response to know if it was approved or not. My SPF and DKIM are good. I did not know about DMARC. I have used that tool you mentioned and indeed is very good.

Comment: You should have received a number of emails from JMRP. The final confirmation should have contained a message like "The request to add "XXX" into our JMRP database has been completed and we will begin to forward complaint messages immediately."

Comment: I am checking and I see that the last email I received was one that contains: `"All parties have signed the envelope 'SNDS-JMRP Contract'."` From then on, I did not get any other mail.

Comment: There should be one more email, which just confirms that the request has been completed - the message body is similar to my previous comment. With the "All parties have signed..." confirmation you would be approved anyhow. Have you tried replying to the last email (checking my email history, Microsoft staff actually responds to that address).

Comment: I have contacted them and got their replies; however, their replies have not been of any help to me. I will go through the whole process one more time and get back to you.

Comment: Can you sign up for JMRP and SNDS if you are not sending from a dedicated IP address? (I'm using Mandrill with a shared pool)  Those services seem directed at IP owners.

Answer (score 8):

The deep link to get whitelisted for Microsoft's email network is:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=614866&clcid

This gives you the form "Sender Information for Outlook.com Delivery"